# ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_DISTANCE'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a small query(ORACLE) for my project to find the distance from a given latitude and longtitude to other latitude and longitude.

Below are the sample data that i used

```
 CREATE table test(id int, title varchar(50), place varchar(20),
 postcode varchar(20), latitude DOUBLE PRECISION, longitude DOUBLE
 PRECISION);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',16.15074,
 -22.74426);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(2,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',16.13725,
 -22.85822);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(3,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.85633,
 -24.72379);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.86949,
 -24.70150);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',15.03118,
 -24.32523);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(6,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.88924,
 -24.29403);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(7,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.89500,
 -24.50000);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(8,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',15.20031,
 -23.16798);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(9,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',16.72662,
 -22.92971);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(10,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',16.60005,
 -22.90818);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',15.19196,
 -23.64427);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(12,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.92331,
 -23.52119);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(13,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.91637,
 -23.60410);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(14,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.92279,
 -23.51720);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(15,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',14.92331,
 -23.52119);

 INSERT INTO test VALUES(16,'sekhar91','kanigiri','91982',15.09882,
 -23.67105);
```

And the Sql Query tha i wrote is

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
      ((ACOS(SIN(16.15074 * 3.141592653 / 180) *
        SIN(latitude * 3.141592653 / 180) +  COS(16.15074 * 3.141592653 / 180
        ) * COS(latitude * 3.141592653 / 180)* COS((-22.74426 -
       longitude)*3.141592653 /180))*180/3.141592653)*60*1.1515)  as distance
 FROM test  
 HAVING distance<=100
```

While executing the above query Oracle is saying

```
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_DISTANCE'
```

What is the reason and where i am wrong ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the issue is with the `HAVING` clause, I removed the `HAVING` and placed your query in a subquery and put the `WHERE` outside with the filter and it works (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99660/4)):

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT id, 
    title, 
    ((ACOS(
          SIN(16.15074 * 3.141592653 / 180) 
          * SIN(latitude * 3.141592653 / 180) 
          + COS(16.15074 * 3.141592653 / 180) 
          * COS(latitude * 3.141592653 / 180)
          * COS((-22.74426 - longitude)*3.141592653 /180))*180/3.141592653)*60*1.1515) as distance 
  FROM test
) x
where distance <= 100
```